# How to have a primary key combination that may have null values?

Tags: oracle, constraints

I have two tables A and B as defined bellow.

```
create table A
(
  A_1 varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
  A_2 varchar2(10),
  A_3 varchar2(10),
  constraint A_PK primary key (A_1,A_2)
)
TABLE A DATA
A_1      |A_2   |A_3
1111     abc     some_text1
1111     null    some_text1
1112     abc     some_text2
1113     def     some_text3

   create table B
   (
     B_1 varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
     B_2 varchar2(10),
     B_3 varchar2(10),
     constraint B_PK primary key (B_1,B_2,B_3),
     constraint B_FK foreign key (B_1,B2) references A(A_1,A_2)
   )
TABLE B DATA
B_1    | B_2    |B_3
1111    abc      text1
1111    null     text2
1111    null     text3
1111    null     text4
```

A_2 column in table A can sometimes be null but the combination of A_1 and A_2 is always unique. I need A_2 be part of primary key because then only I can reference A_1 and A_2 them as foreign keys in table B. Problem here is primary key can not be null. How to solve this problem?
Any response will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You solve this problem by not having this as a primary key. Primary keys cannot be `NULL` or, if they're composite primary keys, cannot contain `NULL`. Make it a unique index instead. Create an autonumber field for the primary key.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a null column in a primary key, but you can create a Unique index with null columns instead.  To get this to work in Oracle 10g, I also had to explicitly add a unique contraint on the table:

```
create table t1 (a1 integer not null,
                 a2 integer,
                 a3 integer);

create unique index t1_uk1 on t1(a1, a2);

alter table t1 add constraint t1_cuk1 unique (a1, a2);

create table b1 (b1 integer not null, b2 integer, b3 integer);

create index b1_idx1 on b1 (b1, b2);

alter table b1 add constraint b1_fk1 
  foreign key (b1, b2) references t1 (a1, a2);
```

However, I tried testing this setup out, and it doesn't work like I expected it would.  For instance:

```
SQL> insert into t1 values (1, null, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into b1 values (1, 1, 1);
insert into b1 values (1, 1, 1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (B1_FK1) violated - parent key not
found
```

OK, so that is what is expected.  No row in parent, so a row should not be allowed in the child table, however:

```
SQL> insert into b1 values (2, null, 1);

1 row created.
```

Looks like it just let that row get inserted without failing, even though there are no rows in t1 with 2, null at all!

```
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from t1;

        A1         A2         A3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1                     1

SQL> select * from b1;

        B1         B2         B3
---------- ---------- ----------
         2                     1
```

I was surprised by this behaviour, as the unique index on t1 behaves as you would expect it to (only 1 row can be inserted with 1, null etc).

Answer (score 2):

If you use "deferrable initially deferred" on the primary key, you can HAVE NULL values...

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can create a composite primary key where one part of it is marked as nullable. Also you can reference it form another table and make it part of its composite primary key.

The following statements are sound in oracle:

```sql
create table A
(
  A_1 varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
  A_2 varchar2(10) NULL,
  A_3 varchar2(10),
  constraint A_PK primary key (A_1,A_2)
)


create table B
(
  B_1 varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
  B_2 varchar2(10) NULL,
  B_3 varchar2(10),
  constraint B_PK primary key (B_1,B_2,B_3),
  constraint B_FK foreign key (B_1,B_2) references A(A_1,A_2)
)
```

You can also insert values in the above tables.

However you still cannot insert null values in `A_2` or `B_2` because of the existence of the `primary key` constraint.

There is a core difference though between setting a `primary key` on columns marked as `null` and setting a `primary key` on columns that are marked as `not null`.

In the latter case, if you disable the `primary key` (by using: `ALTER TABLE A DISABLE PRIMARY KEY;` ) you still have a `check constraint` present (for each non-nullable column) which will prevent null insertions.