# Primary key of a simple 1:1-mapping table with NULL values?

Tags: sql, database-design, primary-key

This feels like a very basic question, but I really don't see the obvious answer at the moment.

I have a simple table that maps object ids between two namespaces:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      id_in_ns1      |     id_in_ns2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         17       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |        NULL      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         NULL        |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

The mapping is basically 1:1, but as you can see, some objects from namespace 1 do not exist in namespace 2, and vice versa, so that there are `NULL` values in the table.

So, what would be the primary key of this table? As a PK cannot be `NULL`, I can neither use `(id_in_ns1)` nor `(id_in_ns2)` nor the composite.

The only idea I have is to replace `NULL` by a definite value, say `-1`, and to use `(id_in_ns1, id_in_ns2)`as PK. However, this feels not only hackish but also "unnormal" because the non-`NULL` (or non-`-1`)) value alone is already sufficient to uniquely identify an object.

Comment: SQL doesn't easily support what would correspond to a relational PK or superkey containing null. SQL PK means UNIQUE NOT NULL. UNIQUE (corresponding to a relational superkey) treats rows that are the same but contain null as not SQL duplicates. (Except SQL Server which is non-standard.) Moreover a FK subrow value with a null does not match the same subrow value elsewhere. [What to do with null values when modeling and normalizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40733625/3404097) To identify subrows that hold nulls use a surrogate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a primary key combination that may have null values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415928/how-to-have-a-primary-key-combination-that-may-have-null-values)

Answer (score 0):

Only add entries that have a valid id on *both* sides. This will effectively get rid of all `NULL` values, allowing you to specify a proper composite key on `(id_in_ns1, id_in_ns2)`.

Ultimately, those *are* the values that allow you to identify a single row and you will not lose relevant information - a `SELECT id_in_ns2 FROM mapping_table WHERE id_in_ns1 = x` will return `NULL` either way, whether there is a `(x, NULL)` row or not.

If you insist on keeping those `NULL`s you could add another column with an artificial (auto incrementing) primary key, but that feels as hacky as using `-1`.

Comment: Thanks, but if there was a third namespace and column id_in_ns3, your suggestion would not work. For instance, the first row could be `1 | 5 | NULL` then and if you omit it, you loose the mapping ns1:1=ns2:5.

Comment: True. Your question explicitly mentions _two_ namespaces, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a synthetic primary key and use unique constraints for the rest:

```
create table mapping (
    mappingId int auto_increment primary key,  -- or whatever for your database
    id_in_ns1 int references ns1(id),
    id_in_ns2 int references ns2(id),
    unique (id_in_ns1),
    unique (id_in_ns2)
);
```

Just one caveat:  some databases only allow one `NULL` value for `UNIQUE` constraints.  You might need to use a filtered unique index instead (or some other mechanism) for this construct.